# How to validate dates and data in currency and percentage format will not show?

Tags: php, validation

The start and due dates need to be validated in this format (example: May 12, 2001), I don't know how to format it that way. The annual interest rate in percentage won't output. The principal and simple interest will also not output in currency format. Where did I mess up?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
       <title>Part 2</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
<h1><?php $today = date('m/d/Y');
                echo "$today <br />"; 
                 date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
                    $currenttime = date('h:i');
                    list($hrs,$mins) = split(':',$currenttime);
                    echo "$hrs:$mins\n";    
             ?></h1>

<form method="post">
    Start: <input name="start" type="text"><br>
    <br>
    Due: <input name="due" type="text"><br>
    <br>
    Annual Interest Rate as a %: <input name="r" type="text"><br>
    <br>
    Principal Amount Borrowed: <input name="P" type="text"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit"><br>
    <br>


    <?php

         $P = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'P',
               FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
        $r = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'r',
            FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
        $interest_rate = round((float)$r * 100 ) . '%';
        $start = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'start',
            FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
         $due = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'due');

                 $t = $start - $due;
                 $l = $P * $interest_rate * $t;
                 $repayment = $P + $interest_rate;

                     // apply currency and percent formatting  

        $r_f = number_format($r, 2);
        $P_f ='$'.number_format($P, 2);
        $l_f ='$'.number_format($l, 2);
        $repayment_f ='$'.number_format($repayment, 2);

          if(!empty($_POST['start']) ) {
              echo "Loan Start Date: ".$_POST['start'];
          }             
          if(!empty($_POST['due']) ) {
              echo " <br>Loan Due Date: ".$_POST['due'];
          }              
          if(!empty($_POST['r']) ) {
              echo " <br>Annual Rate of Simple Interest as a %: ".$_POST['r_f'];
          }             
          if(!empty($_POST['P']) ) {
              echo " <br>Principal Amount: ".$_POST['P_f'];
          }
          if(!empty($_POST['l']) ) {
              echo " <br>Simple Interest Due: ".$_POST['l_f'];
          }
          if(!empty($_POST['repayment']) ) {
              echo " <br>Repayment Amount: ".$_POST['repayment_f'];
          }

        ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` doesn't have named elements with name attribute such as:
`name='r_f'`,
 `name='P_f'`,
 `name='l_f'`,
 `name='l'`,
 `name='repayment'`

Therefore, you can not get those values in `$_POST` array:
`$_POST['r_f']`, `$_POST['l']`, `$_POST['P_f']`, `$_POST['l_f']`, `$_POST['repayment_f']`, `$_POST['repayment']`

Answer (score 0):

your date format will be

date('M dS, Y'); [Clickhere](https://eval.in/510917)

or if you dont want the english suffix st, nd after day then just use date('M d, Y')

hope this help.

Comment: is that the validation for the declaring variables? e.g. ** $start = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'start',
                FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);**